# Speed up iterating over characters in long strings

Tags: python, pandas, string, lambda, nested-loops

I have a code that takes a DNA string, in which only 4 characters are found: A, C, T and G, for example "ATACAAG", and for each character if finds the 3 other possible characters. The code includes a loop for the string and another loop for a list of the possible characters. The issue is that the strings are very long: up to hundreds of thousands of characters, so it's not fast and the computer get heated (it's fans start working fast).

I'm looking for a faster way to do it. I tried list comprehension but it's still rather slow. I also tried calling the code as a function from a pandas lambda and it still takes about a minute for each string. Is that the best I can get?

For each character, the code records 3 alternatives in separate lines in a file.

The code:

```
bases = set(list('ACGT'))
alts = {base: list(bases.difference(base)) for base in bases}

def get_variants(data, output_path):    # pb: position base, b: base
    [open(output_path + f'/{data.symbol}_variants.txt', 'a').writelines(
        [f'{data.chromosome}\t{data.end + index}\t{data.end + index}\t{pb}/{b}\t{data.strand}\n' for b in alts[pb]])
        for index, pb in enumerate(data.sequence)]
```

Calling the function for "ATACAAG":

```
get_variants(pandas.Series({'symbol': 'XYZ', 'sequence': 'ATACAAG', 'chromosome': 12, 'start': 9067664, 'end': 9067671, 'strand': '-'}),
             'write_an_existing_output_directory_path_here')
```

The output is arranged in a file in the following columns:

```
chromosome number, start position, end position, original character/alternative character, strand (can + or -)
```

It yields the following lines in the file XYZ_variants.txt:

```
12  9067664 9067664 A/T -
12  9067664 9067664 A/G -
12  9067664 9067664 A/C -
12  9067665 9067665 T/A -
12  9067665 9067665 T/G -
12  9067665 9067665 T/C -
12  9067666 9067666 A/T -
12  9067666 9067666 A/G -
12  9067666 9067666 A/C -
12  9067667 9067667 C/T -
12  9067667 9067667 C/A -
12  9067667 9067667 C/G -
12  9067668 9067668 A/T -
12  9067668 9067668 A/G -
12  9067668 9067668 A/C -
12  9067669 9067669 A/T -
12  9067669 9067669 A/G -
12  9067669 9067669 A/C -
12  9067670 9067670 G/T -
12  9067670 9067670 G/A -
12  9067670 9067670 G/C -
```

Thanks.

Comment: please provide an example of your input file/dataframe

Comment: I have. The question includes a `pandas.Series` object, which is an example for a row in the dataframe.

Comment: If you want to iterate over every character in string, then no, there is no faster method. List comprehension only makes the codes smaller, not speed up the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

Starting from a dataframe:

```
  symbol sequence chromosome    start      end strand
0    XYZ  ATACAAG         12  9067664  9067671      -
```

I would `explode` the sequence, `reindex` to have all combinations of A/C/G/T and keep only that where the initial base is different

```
import numpy as np

df2 = df.assign(base=df['sequence'].apply(list)).explode('base').reset_index()
df2 = (df2.reindex(df2.index.repeat(4))
          .assign(variant=np.tile(list('ACGT'), len(df2)))
          .loc[lambda d: d['base'].ne(d['variant'])]
          .assign(var=lambda d:d['base']+'/'+d['variant'])
       )
```

Intermediate output:

```
>>> df2.head()
   index symbol sequence chromosome    start      end strand base variant  var
0      0    XYZ  ATACAAG         12  9067664  9067671      -    A       C  A/C
0      0    XYZ  ATACAAG         12  9067664  9067671      -    A       G  A/G
0      0    XYZ  ATACAAG         12  9067664  9067671      -    A       T  A/T
1      0    XYZ  ATACAAG         12  9067664  9067671      -    T       A  T/A
1      0    XYZ  ATACAAG         12  9067664  9067671      -    T       C  T/C
```

Then export:

```
df2[['start', 'end', 'var', 'strand']].to_csv('variants.txt', sep='\t', index=False, header=None)
```

example output (first lines):

```
9067664 9067671 A/C -
9067664 9067671 A/G -
9067664 9067671 A/T -
9067664 9067671 T/A -
9067664 9067671 T/C -
9067664 9067671 T/G -
9067664 9067671 A/C -
9067664 9067671 A/G -
9067664 9067671 A/T -
9067664 9067671 C/A -
```

##### optimization

Now we remove everything that is not needed to keep the size minimal:

```
df2 = (df.drop(columns=['symbol', 'chromosome'])
         .assign(sequence=df['sequence'].apply(list))
         .explode('sequence').reset_index(drop=True)
      )
df2 = (df2.reindex(df2.index.repeat(4))
          .assign(var=np.tile(list('ACGT'), len(df2)))
          .loc[lambda d: d['sequence'].ne(d['var'])]
          .assign(var=lambda d:d['sequence']+'/'+d['var'])
       )
df2[['start', 'end', 'var', 'strand']].to_csv('variants.txt', sep='\t', index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is that a good approach considering that the sequences are hundreds of thousands of characters?

I tried using your code and got a dataframe of around 3.3 million rows. In the future it will run on a server with lots of memory and cores, so it might be OK.

Comment: Well, if you have millions of rows, it will take time no matter what. The good thing here is that your rows are probably independent, so it's a perfect case to split the input into smaller dataframes, apply on different threads/cores and join the output ;) Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Also, the output includes the chromosome in the first column, so the first code line will be `df2 = (df.drop(columns=['symbol'])`, the fifth line will be `df2 = (df2.reindex(df2.index.repeat(4))`, and the last code line `df2[['chromosome', 'start', 'end', 'var', 'strand']]`?

Comment: Seems correct, give it a try on the test sample ;)

Comment: I wish to save each symbol / gene name in a separate file, so I split the dataframe into multiple dataframes, and used your suggested code on each of them separately. Would you do it differently?

Comment: You can keep 'symbol' in the final dataframe and use `groupby` + a loop to save each group as csv. Btw, if your question is resolved, good practice would be to mark the answer as accepted and follow ups should be asked as new questions ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239580/discussion-between-py-man-and-mozway).